# SQL query aggregating values isn't working?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my query:

```
SELECT customers.state, SUM( orders.quantity * items.unitcost ) AS 'value of orders'
FROM customers, items, orders
WHERE customers.custID = orders.custID
AND orders.itemID = items.itemID
GROUP BY customers.state
LIMIT 0 , 50
```

Is there something wrong with it? It's giving answers that look like they might be correct, but some of them are just a tiny bit off when checked manually (none of the tables have more than fifty rows). This seems completely bizarre to me, and I can't work out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is input data and what is expected result?

Comment: You are doing a `CROSS JOIN` (join everything on everything), whereas you probably want an `INNER JOIN`. I appreciate that you are kind of making an `INNER JOIN` though the `WHERE` clause. But try rewriting it to see if that helps. Also execute the query without the `GROUP BY` clause to see what data you get and see where the query is possibly going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

hope this will help::

```
SELECT 
customers.state, SUM( orders.quantity * items.unitcost ) AS 'value of orders'
FROM 
customers 
inner join orders on (customers.custID = orders.custID)
inner join items  on (orders.itemID = items.itemID),
GROUP BY customers.state
LIMIT 0 , 50
```

Comment: Sadly gave the same error... might be a problem with the data.